# When delivery radiobutton is checked the textarea is required

Tags: onepage-checkout, javascript, form-validation

On my checkoutpage I have added a deliverydate textarea. 
Some visitors don't fill the textarea which is a problem.

I need the textarea to be required when checking the Deliver radiobutton.
On default it is selected and required. 
And when checking the Pickup radiobutton the textarea isn't required anymore. (its hidden with js see below)

I think I need to add required to the textarea and when checking radiobutton Pickup the required needs to be removed with javascript?

```
<textarea rows="4" name="shipping_arrival_comments" id="shipping_arrival_comments" required ></textarea>
```

Here below is how my (stripped) form looks like:
How can I do this?

```
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="">
    Pickup<br />
    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" /><br /><br />

    Deliver<br />
    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="tablerate_bestway" id="s_method_tablerate_bestway" checked="checked" class="radio" /><br /><br />

    <div id="deliv-hold">
        Deliver date<br />
        <textarea rows="4" name="shipping_arrival_comments" id="shipping_arrival_comments"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function check() {
        var items = document.getElementsByName('shipping_method');
        var v = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].checked) {
                v = items[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }

        var required = (v == "tablerate_bestway");
        document.getElementById("deliv-hold").style.display = required ? "block" : "none";
    }

    check();
</script>
```

The "Submit button":

```
<button onclick="shippingMethod.save()" class="button" type="button"><span><span>Next step</span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

add the classes `class="input-text required-entry"` to your textarea:

```
<textarea rows="4" name="shipping_arrival_comments" id="shipping_arrival_comments" class="input-text required-entry"></textarea>
```

Comment: When I choose "pickup" that textarea isn't required anymore and is hidden. There isn't a submit button either. There is a onclick function so I think there needs to be added some JS to fix this but I can't find any solution